# can't run an other paragraph in Zeppelin after VectorAssembler.transfrom

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin 0.7.1 and spark 2.1.0.

I ve got some data in the dataframe 'dataset' :

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| index |var 1  |var 2  |var 3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2     | 1     | 0     | 1     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

and I want, in order to make a linear regression, to put every column in one vector column :

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler


assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['var 1', 'var 2', 'var 3'], outputCol='features')
output = assembler.transform(dataset)
```

Well, after running this, in Zeppelin, I can't run an other paragraph. I must restart my interpreter... 
If someone has an idea where the problem may come from.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 0.7.2 of Zeppelin should solve your problem.
We had the same problem, we just tested it with the same version and this upgrade and it was fine.

regards